# Custom UINavigationBar image with default gradient and lines

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, customization, appearance

I want to use **custom graphics** as UINavigationBar background:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]
    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile"]
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Works fine, except I lost **default gradient, white line at top and black line at bottom** of the titlebar. Any ideas how to get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up and **added gradient and lines into the texture**. Of course this meant that I had to hardcode texture height as 44 pixels == navigation bar size for vertical orientation.

Not happy with the solution, but it does work without any problems.